# При вводе input меняет цвет

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input, materialize-css

Всем привет. При вводе текста, поле импута меняется с прозрачного на белый.
Кусок взят с materializecss . Пишу на реакте.
Мне кажется ответ где-то на поверхности, но я всю голову сломал уже.
Код прилагаю, и скрины на всякий.
Прошу камнями не кидаться, я новичок)
заранее спасибо!

```html
  <input
                        className='validate'
                        placeholder='search'
                        type='search'
                        value={this.state.search}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            this.setState({ search: e.target.value })
                        }
                        onKeyDown={this.handleKey}
                    />
```

[image: Было]

[image: Стало]

Comment: явно теряются стили, я проверил в обычном html такого нет, а тут мало инфы для ответа, нужно минимально работающий пример

Comment: а  что происходит тут this.handleKey ?

Comment: handleKey = (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            this.props.searchOption(this.state.search, this.state.type);
        }
    };        Если вставить код в новый файл как человек снизу проверил, то работает. Но в общей картине проекта вылезает такая ерунда. Грешу на то, что  кусок взят с подключенного  https://materializecss.com . Возможно там что-то заложено. Видимо придется переписывать самому :/

Comment: а как прописан класс в css validate ?

Comment: .validate {
  background-color: transparent;
}  я на самом деле многое перепробовал здесь. Результата вобще 0

Comment: а если попробовать input.validate ? дело в том что у меня просто .validate не отрабатывало тоже, возможно какой-то внутренний конфликт с сss. а самый верный способ прописать инлайн стилем должно по любому работать `style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}`

Comment: Друг, спасибо большое за помощь. Вопрос решился. На самом деле у этого сервиса гугла есть вкладка 'color', где выложена палитра с цветами и прописаны названия. В самом низу там есть прозрачность. Ее и надо было прописать в самом названии класса  <input className='validate N/A transparent' />. 4 часа моего времени, вашего, и первый пост на SOF. Спасибо большое за то, что откликнулся!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это собственно не ответ, а пример того когда все работает, т.е. проблема не в указанном коде. Прошу камнями не кидаться, я **не** новичок) В комментарии такую демонстрацию не написать.

```css
body{
  background-color: #2c5e82;
}
input.validate{
  background-color:transparent;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script type="text/babel">
      class MyInput extends React.Component {
         constructor(){
           super();
           this.state = { search: ""};
         }
         render(){
            return (
            <input
               className='validate'
               placeholder='search'
               type='search'
               value={this.state.search}
               onChange={(e) => this.setState({ search: e.target.value})}
               onKeyDown={this.handleKey}
             />
         )}
      }
      const App = () => {
        return (
          <MyInput/>
        );
      };

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```